# Plotting renormalization group flow diagram from recursion relation

Tags: plotting

How do I plot a flow diagram (given certain initial conditions, the trajectory in y-x space) for a RG (renormalization group) flow given by the following recursion relations?

\begin{eqnarray}
x^{\prime}&=&\frac{x(1+y)^2}{(x+y)(1+xy)} \\
 y^{\prime}&=&\frac{y(x+y)}{1+xy}  \\
\end{eqnarray}

I have explored several options such as RSolve, Equation trekker package on Mathematica, but none of these can be used to plot a flow diagram for a continuous transformation.

Comment: Is it something like [this type of stream plot](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/streamplot_demo_features.html) that you're looking for?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your notation. Do you mean that $x'$ is the derivative of $x$ with respect to some parameter $t$ so that $x(t),y(t)$ denotes your flow? If so, all you have is a system of differential equations and you can plot the trajectory for a number of starting points easily using, for example, Maple.

Comment: Do you have some typical initial conditions?

Comment: You should also be able to calculate a phase portrait using something like `quiver` in both MATLAB and in Python (via matplotlib).